# problems with web service values in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, web-services, asp.net-core, angular10

I have a project with net core that uses the angular template, I have an authentication web service, when I send username and password I receive the data correctly, but it cannot read the properties of the object that I receive, that is, the name of the user or the object

```
    respuestaAuth: RespuestaAutenticacion;//interface
    
this._loginUserService.postAutenticacionUsuario(datosAutenticacion)
        .subscribe(respuestaAutenticacion=>
        {
          
            this.respuestaAuth =respuestaAutenticacion;
            console.log('respuesta autenticacion : >>', respuestaAutenticacion);
            console.log('respuesta binaria autenticacion : >>', this.respuestaAuth.Permiso);
            console.log('respuesta binaria autenticacion : >>', this.respuestaAuth);
            if(this.respuestaAuth.Permiso)
            { .... actions}
```

In this line all the properties of the object appear correctly, user name identification ...

```
console.log ('binary response authentication: >>', this.responseAuth);
```

in this line I cannot obtain the value of the object, it appears undefined

```
console.log ('binary response authentication: >>', this.responseAuth.Permiso);
```

I don't understand why this happens, I had already tried this application before using net core and angular separately, now that I'm doing it with the angula 10 template in net core I get this error, I don't know what else to try, and why is this happening when changing to anet core with the angular 10 template

Comment: Could you paste the response of your endpoint here?

Comment: Could be an issue with case sensitivity. Try `this.responseAuth.permiso`.